# incenter point coordinates given the coordinates of the three vertices of a triangle ABC

Tags: geometry

I have the following equations: [image: 4x-y+2=0] , [image: x-4y-8=0] , [image: x+4y-8=0].These equations determine a triangle.I have to find the incenter coordinates.

I found the coordinates of the triangle vertices and all I know is that I take the incenter point [image: I(a,b)] then [image: \frac{\left | 4a-b+2 \right |}{\sqrt{17}} = \frac{\left | a-4b-8 \right |}{\sqrt{17}} = \frac{\left | a+4b-8 \right |}{\sqrt{17}}]

How to continue?

Comment: Hint: The internal bisector of the angle at (8, 0) is the x-axis. So b = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

It is know that for a $\triangle ABC$, suppose its length is $a,b,c$, with the vertices being $(x_i, y_i)$ where $i\in \{A,B,C\}$.

Then the formula is given by

$$\left( \frac{ax_A+bx_B+cx_C}{a+b+c},\frac{ay_A+by_B+cy_C}{a+b+c}\right)$$

A proof of the formula can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1413734/306553).

You have found the coordinates, hence it should be possible for you to find the lenght of the sides easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I did it.